# Prometheus Alertmanager: is dynamic alert name possible

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Can we have dynamic alert names for Alertmanager alert rule?

Such as:

```
    - alert: "Dependency Status - {{ $labels.serviceName }} unhealthy "
      expr: 100*avg_over_time(dependency_status{}[30m]) < 90
      for: 1m
      labels:
        severity: warning
        action: page
        pager: pagerDutyService
      annotations:
        summary: "Dependency Unhealthy - Service: {{ $labels.serviceName }}"
        information: "Dependency Status availability rate over 30m for service "{{ $labels.serviceName }} at {{ $value }}%"
```

Comment: In short yes, you will need to ensure that your expression is also able to match on `serviceName`

Comment: @ken-tsoi, Do you have any luck using labels in alert name? For me it does not work in alert name but just in the summary of the alert.

Comment: @AdeelAhmad, no luck, I finally needed to make different rules for different entries.